# Why File launcher does not work in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I've just installed `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` on my computer. When I click on the file launcher icon, then it opens and immediately closes.

If I type `nautilus` in the terminal it shows `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Please help me what can be done?

Comment: Is this a fresh clean install? Very unexpected in that case. Check whether there are also other issues. It could be related to a hardware issue, but then you would see other problems now and then. Perhaps also add information on your hardware to your question (use "edit")

Comment: There's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1820859) related to 20.10